# How to retrieve query string that starts with # instead of ? in .NET and save it into JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm trying to receive the token which is one of the parameters send in a request that looks something like this:

```
https://myapp.com/myApp/oauthcallback#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJQQ&token_type=bearer&expires_in=120&state=
```

The problem is that the delimiters is # instead of ? and no matter that i do i cannot substract the parameters as they are not received in a request in my application.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/oauthcallback")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public string Oauthcallback()
{      
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;
}
```

the method doesn't return anything, but if i change it to ? then it returns the query string.
I need to do the same and make it a json but with # instead of ?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Because it's the same answer. HTTP is HTTP, web browsers are web browsers. The backend being C# or PHP doesn't change that.

Comment: I think i misunderstood the question got you.